# how can i separate an iterated struts radio button item?

Tags: struts2, iterator, radio-button

How can i separate an iterated struts radio button item?
I also tried using some of [these](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html)
,but probably in the wrong way.

What i wish to do is separate each item from the first iterator (the paths), with a `<br>` or any separator.

I guess this is happening because the html tags are interpreted first, before the struts tags?

```
<s:form action="actionConfirmBooking">
        <s:iterator var = "pathList" value="results">
            <s:iterator var = "flightList" value="pathList">
                 <s:radio name="flightSelected" list="flightList" listKey = "flightid"   id = "flightid" value = "flightid"/>
                        $$$$$$$$$$$
            </s:iterator>*************
        </s:iterator>&&&&&&&&
        <s:submit label="Submit" />#############
</s:form>
```

[image]

Comment: Look at the generated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `theme="simple"` to prevent Struts generating additional XHTML code by using the default theme (XHTML):

```
<s:form action="actionConfirmBooking" theme="simple">
... 
</s:form>
```